# What is a good technique for poll result bars?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, css

I am creating some polling software and am currently researching techniques for doing poll result graph bars. Nothing complicated, just some simple results bars.

I was wondering if there are any tried and true best methods for this. The best that comes to my mind is having a div container for each bar, and then an image or some other element where you set the size (width) equal to the options result percentage (inline css).

Example of this

**strong text**

```
// Option 1 Results
<div>
   <span style="background-color: #ff0000; width: 33%"></span>
</div>

// Option 2 Results
<div>
   <span style="background-color: #ff0000; width: 16%"></span>
</div>
```

etc...

Any know of any better techniques, or is this pretty much how most do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's a good way to do it.

Here's the same idea with more refinement:

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/dJHER/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="pollBars">
    <span class="t1" style="width: 10%">69</span>
    <span class="t1" style="width: 20%">100</span>
    <span class="t1" style="width: 70%">200</span>
    <span class="t2" style="width: 90%">666</span>
    <span class="t2" style="width: 120%">Over 9000!!</span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.pollBars {
    width: 300px;
    background: #ccc
}
.pollBars span {
    display: block;

    padding: 3px;
    margin: 7px 0;

    font: bold 14px/1 sans-serif;

    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;

    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #444;
}

.t1 {
    color: #fff;

    border: 1px solid red;

    background: #f85032; /* old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f85032 0%, #f16f5c 50%, #f6290c 51%, #f02f17 71%, #e73827 100%); /* firefox */

    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f85032), color-stop(50%,#f16f5c), color-stop(51%,#f6290c), color-stop(71%,#f02f17), color-stop(100%,#e73827)); /* webkit */

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f85032', endColorstr='#e73827',GradientType=0 ); /* ie */
}

.t2 {
    color: #fff;

    border: 1px solid blue;

    background: #6db3f2; /* old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #6db3f2 0%, #54a3ee 50%, #3690f0 51%, #1e69de 100%); /* firefox */

    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#6db3f2), color-stop(50%,#54a3ee), color-stop(51%,#3690f0), color-stop(100%,#1e69de)); /* webkit */

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#6db3f2', endColorstr='#1e69de',GradientType=0 ); /* ie */
}
```

Comment: It was no problem :) I used this to quickly get the gradients: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/