# Html table td problem

Tags: html

Hi I'm trying to create one table with two 4 rows each with 2 tds.
I'm specifying the different width for my tds but every td taking same width why?
here below is my code

```
<table style="width:400px;">
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color:Red; width:50px;"></td>
        <td style="background-color:Red;width:70px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color:Red; width:54px;"></td>
        <td style="background-color:Red; width:80px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color:Red; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="background-color:Red; width:40px;"></td>
    </tr>
</table>![enter image description here][1]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi I have uploaded the image. I want to split each bar with 3 colors.

Comment: You want something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293049/what-is-a-good-technique-for-poll-result-bars/5293117#5293117

Comment: Hi thirydot Yes almost same but I want to split each bar with 3 parts each part contain different color and bars width should take from codebehind in asp.net.

Comment: Have a go at doing it yourself. You should be able to take my demo apart and figure out how it works.

Answer (score 4):

All cells in an HTML column must have the same width.

You probably shouldn't be using a `<table>`.

Comment: I don't think you meant to say "All columns in an HTML table must have the same width."

Comment: Indeed. A table is a collection of data grouped by rows and columns, it isn't a bar chart.

Comment: Thanks. Cloud you suggest me what sholuld be the alternative.I need to create the bars based on the number(width).

Comment: Then you want a set of `<div>`s, not a `<table>`.

Answer (score 3):

The td's are taking the width of the first row. And none of the rows add up to 400px. It's doing the best it can with the specifications you have put in.

Answer (score 3):

Because a column has only one width : all rows share the same width for a given column.

Answer (score 2):

When you give a width to a `<td>` it becomes the width of the *column*, and all `<td>`s in the *column* will take the same width.

If your data is actually a table (a listing for instance), you can achieve different widths for different tables using `rowspan`. `rowspan` actually merges two columns, so you can have some `<td>`s bigger than the other.

If your data is not a actual table (a feedback form for instance) and you are trying to use a table just for alignment, you [should not be doing so](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tableless_web_design). There are better ways for this.