# JQuery multiple percentage bar based on votes cast

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scale

Hey all i have a very tricky poll that i am working on.

I have a questionnaire that once you select one of the check-boxes you submit your answer and then in the same div it will hide the poll and show the results so far that have been cast in percentage bars showing the results (as a percent) on each option.

Below is basically what i want it to look like. I have the results showing now as a percentage e.g. 66%, 33% etc etc. So how would i go about outputting the results into percentage bars like below.

The results are all generated server side so i just need to convert the percentages to the bars.

[image]

Comment: two div one into the other, one with fix size in px and other inside in percentage

Comment: May I suggest [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293049/what-is-a-good-technique-for-poll-result-bars)

Comment: Why can't you use the percentage of each result as the width percentage for the bar?  % is valid in css

Comment: Here is a demo to illustrate http://jsbin.com/ipahuh/3/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see your picture.

If you want to draw percentage like a progress bar, you could have one DIV with specified width (as your background) and a second div inside representing the progress value.

```
<div id="percentageContainer">
    <div id="percentageValue"></div>
</div>
```

With some CSS rules, you can easily draw what you desire.

For example, set your first DIV with a **fixed width** and **relative position**, and set your second width with **absolute position** (positionned on left top) and a **width set to 0**.

Then tou can update the width of the second width to simulate your progress bar.

Here is a full working example : http://jsfiddle.net/ZK3VK/

Comment: Thanks a heap. I have used the code from yours to modify my one one to inject the "#percentageValue" with the results from my database. Works great and relatively little code. Nice work!